# osx Store Content from WebView as Image

Tags: swift, image, macos, webview

How do I store the content of an `WebView` as image in a variable (object property)?

A kind of custom editor is used to create a math formula which is rendered and displayed in a `WebView`:

[image]

After editing the formula should get stored as image property of an object. I need that formula image in order to show the formula in a `NSTableView` later without having endless `WebViews`in the table.

Can anybody guide me how to get the formula image from the `WebView`?

Thanks!

Comment: If you knew the coordinates of the rectangle where the formula is displayed, you could use Core Graphics function for making screenshots: `func CGDisplayCreateImage(_ display: CGDirectDisplayID, rect: CGRect) -> CGImage?`

Comment: ok, thanks for the feedback. I will check that out.